# Split a string based on specific substring or pattern in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, split

Thanks for all your help on my previous question. It was of good use.

Now there is another question which am stuck with. Its based on my previous question. I have my cleansed input and I want to split the main company name and put it in separate column based on some substrings or patterns.

Here is my input:

```
Original_Input                                                 Cleansed_Input
Iris Diagnostics, a Division of Iris International Inc         Iris Diagnostics a Division of Iris 
                                                               International Inc
GINGI-PAK a division of The Belport Co., Inc.                  GINGIPAK a division of The Belport Co Inc
Plastiflex Healthcare Division of Plastiflex Group NV          Plastiflex Healthcare Division of 
                                                               Plastiflex Group NV
Heuer International (A division of GST Corporation Limited)    Heuer International A division of GST 
                                                               Corporation Limited
Arrow International, Inc. (subsidiary of Teleflex, Inc.)       Arrow International Inc subsidiary of 
                                                               Teleflex Inc
Filtertek, B.V. (An ITW Medical Company)                       Filtertek BV An ITW Medical Company
Fitz c/o YBI                                                   Fitz co YBI
```

My expected output is:

```
Original_Input                                                 Cleansed_Input
Iris Diagnostics, a Division of Iris International Inc         Iris Diagnostics a Division of Iris International Inc
GINGI-PAK a division of The Belport Co., Inc.                  GINGIPAK a division of The Belport Co Inc
Plastiflex Healthcare Division of Plastiflex Group NV          Plastiflex Healthcare Division of Plastiflex Group NV
Heuer International (A division of GST Corporation Limited)    Heuer International A division of GST Corporation Limited
Arrow International, Inc. (subsidiary of Teleflex, Inc.)       Arrow International Inc subsidiary of Teleflex Inc
Filtertek, B.V. (An ITW Medical Company)                       Filtertek BV An ITW Medical Company
Fitz c/o YBI                                                   Fitz co YBI

Parent_company
Iris Diagnostics
GINGIPAK 
Plastiflex Healthcare 
Heuer International
Arrow International Inc 
Filtertek BV
Fitz
```

So the string or words before 'A division of', 'Division of', '(a', '(an', 'subsidiary of', 'C/O' should be taken and put as Parent_company.

My piece of code I used is as below:

```
data['Parent_Company'] = re.sub('A division of','',str(data['Cleansed_Input']))
```

Am not getting the required output. I want the string from those delimiters to end to be blanked and only the company name to be placed or else want the names before those delimiters to be split and placed as Parent_company.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with an regex an apply. Something like this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def get_parent_company(input):
    keywords = ["a division of", "co", "subsidiary of", "division of","an"]
    regex = r"(.*?)(\b{}\b)".format("\\b|\\b".join(keywords))
    matches = re.finditer(regex, input, re.IGNORECASE)
    for match in matches:
        return match.group(1).strip()

df["Parent_Company"] = df["Cleansed_Input"].apply(get_parent_company)
print(df)
```

## Output:

```
                                      Cleansed_Input           Parent_Company
0  Iris Diagnostics a Division of Iris Internatio...         Iris Diagnostics 
1          GINGIPAK a division of The Belport Co Inc                 GINGIPAK 
2  Plastiflex Healthcare Division of Plastiflex G...    Plastiflex Healthcare 
3  Heuer International A division of GST Corporat...      Heuer International 
4  Arrow International Inc subsidiary of Teleflex...  Arrow International Inc 
5                Filtertek BV An ITW Medical Company             Filtertek BV 
6                                        Fitz co YBI                     Fitz
```

## Explanation

The final regex looks like this:

```
(.*?)(\ba division of\b|\bco\b|\bsubsidiary of\b|\bdivision of\b|\ban\b)
```

`(.*?)` is the capture group we want. It means all characters `.*` but only as few times as possible `?`. This is needed so that it matches the first occurence. Otherwise our match for

```
GINGIPAK a division of The Belport Co Inc
```

would be

```
GINGIPAK a division of The Belport
```

Because the last match would be `Co` which is also one of our keywords but we want to match the first one `a division of`.

The rest are all the keywords we want with an OR `|` so that it matches any of them. We put `\b` before and after so that it will match the exact word otherwise the match for

```
Heuer International A division of GST Corporation Limited
```

would be

```
Heuer International A division of GST
```

Because in Corporation we have co, but we only want to match co as a whole.

And in the end we take the first match `match.group(1).strip()` which is `(.*?)` and remove ending whitespaces.

Comment: I need one more help, I am always getting confused with the regex pattern. Can you just explain please for this code.

Comment: Understood thank you so much . @Boendal can you also help me on my question posted before. Title is : Split and replace in one dataframe based on a condition with another dataframe in pandas

Comment: Hi @Boendal. There is another type of input. Input: OMRON (DALIAN) CO., LTD. (PLANT 1)   Output: OMRON CO., LTD. (PLANT 1). So here the middle part is removed and rest is put as main company and that middle part is placed as alias company. Can you help me on this

Comment: @DhanalakshmiV what do you mean with main and alias company. you only have a cleansed input and a parent company.

Comment: Yup sorry . Cleansed_input is the input column, Parent company is the main company column that is output and alias company is another output column. So from the cleansed_input we need to split the string as Main company and Alias company .

Comment: Input(Cleansed_input): OMRON (DALIAN) CO., LTD. (PLANT 1) Output1(Main_Company): OMRON CO., LTD. (PLANT 1)                                                               Output2(Alias_Company): (DALIAN)

Comment: @DhanalakshmiV basically that won't work. If you compare the input `Fitz co YBI` with the input `OMRON (DALIAN) CO., LTD. (PLANT 1)` you want 2 different output but you have similar input. Or rather there is no rule how to distinguish this two. Therefore I can't think about a way to solve that problem.